# Avoiding creating multiple controller instances

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to get some data with ajax, and these variables are being initialized in controller constructor and then changing based on values that gets on delegates.

But the problem is that when i get data with ajax it returns always default value (0), changes by delegates doesnt affect variables when the ajax call is executing. I guess its creating a new instance of controller everytime ajax is executing.

```
    private int waiting;
    private int all;

    public HomeController()
    {
        all = 0;
        waiting = 0;
        Connect();
    }

    public async Task Connect()
    {
        pbx.WaitingCallsChanged += Changed;
        pbx.PhoneCallsChanged += PhoneChanged;
    }

    public void PhoneChanged(object sender, PhoneChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        all = e.Phone.ActiveCalls.Count;
    }

    private void Changed(object sender, WaitingCallsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        waiting = e.Queue.WaitingCalls.Count;
    }

    public ActionResult GetWaiting()
    {
        return Json(new { queue1 = waiting, all = all }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: I strongly suspect the problem is that a new instance of `HomeController` is being created for each request, so your `GetWaiting()` method is being called on a completely different instance to the one that the delegates are modifying. It's hard to tell with so little context though. (We don't know what `server` is, for a start...)

Comment: Your calling a server method. Each time you do that a new instance of your controller is created and your variables are their default (i.e. `0` because they are `int`)

Comment: Try googling "asp mvc object lifetimes". Find a good visual diagram. Let it sink in. Weep.

Comment: @JonSkeet I just changed my server variable to pbx, because that server its just a simple library that i am using for getting some calls. What do u think it would be best to do that?

Comment: @StephenMuecke That server is just a library that i am using to get some calls, it has nothing to do with the server. p.s i changed the name to pbx

Comment: Regardless of the variable name, we still have no context as to what it does or how it does it. But fundamentally, that will only be changing variables in the instance of the class whose code (but not declaration) you've shown us. If a new instance is created for the `GetWaiting()` method, that's not going to see any changes.

Comment: @JonSkeet is there any other method to get data with ajax or whatever without creating a new instance everytime?

Comment: I don't know - but that's got nothing to do with delegates, and you could change your question to be very specific about that. You could potentially use static fields instead of instance fields so that it doesn't matter, but you need to be careful about race conditions, partial updates etc.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you, i just changed the question title. Dont u think it would be the same with static fields while it creates a new instance everytime?

Comment: Um, no. If that confuses you, you should research what static means.

Comment: And I wasn't suggesting just changing the question title. The whole thrust of the question could change to "avoiding creating multiple controller instances"

Comment: @JonSkeet Just changed the title and contect. I take a look at those statics.

Comment: You cannot avoid creating multiple instances of the controller (the web is stateless). You need to persist the values somewhere (e.g. a database or external file, or `Session`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke well thank, external file(.json) ose Session would be great. But just wanted to ask u: Which do u think it would be faster writing a getting from .json file or Session?

Comment: In-memory `Session` will be faster, although writing to a simple text or xml file will be insignificant

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok then. Thank you so much.